# How to solve AvroTypeException: Unknown union branch

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, kafka-producer-api

I'm working with the Kafka CLI. I'm using the command `kafka-avro-console-producer` to produce a record to a topic.

This is the schema:

```
{
    "connect.name": "datachanges.article.Envelope",
    "name": "Envelope",
    "namespace": "datachanges.article",
    "type": "record",
    "fields": [
      {
        "default": null,
        "name": "before",
        "type": [
          "null",
          {
            "connect.name": "datachanges.article.Value",
            "name": "Value",
            "type": "record",
            "fields": [
              { "name": "id", "type": "int" }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

And this is the test data:

```
{ "before": { "id": 345530 } }
```

I keep getting the error:

```
org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Unknown union branch id
```

I get the same error with this payload:

```
{ "before": { "id": { "int": 345530 } } }
```

Please mind that I cannot change the schema, because it is automatically generated by the Debezium connector.

I have read this post, but the solution doesn't work for me:
[org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Unknown union branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49926146/org-apache-avro-avrotypeexception-unknown-union-branch)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input should be something like this.

```
{
    "before": {
        "Value": {
            "id": {
                "int": 345530
            }
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "before": {
        "Value": {
            "id": 345530
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you friend, that was the solution. In addition to that, I also had to add the namespace, like this ```{"before": {"datachanges.article.Value": {"id": 345530}}}```